# Synergy Keyboard Mapping

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, synergy

Server - Windows 7
Client - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I Run synergyc using lightdm.conf so that I can use the keyboard to login.

Every now and then, my keyboard mapping or characters will get scrambled and I won't be able to login to my Ubuntu box because the password will by typed incorrectly as a result of this.

Example: 
Period . will become / 
Everything will be in Uppercase 
and so on...

The only way to fix it is to restart synergyc in /usr/local/etc

Anyone having the same or similar problems?